# How can I redirect wp-admin to another url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

How can I redirect user from `wp-admin` to another custom page, for example I want to redirect this url:

```
http://example.com/wp-admin
```

to:

```
http://example.com/custom
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wp_redirect( $location, $status );
exit;
```

OR try like this

```
wp_redirect( home_url( '/custom/' ) );
exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would probably be to create a `.htaccess` file in your `webroot directory`.

Afterwards write this into it:

```
Redirect /wp-admin http://www.example.com/custom
```

Quite self explanatory. `Redirect` from first link `/wp-admin` to second link `http://www.example.com/custom`

Another way would probably be to use wordpress `wp_redirect()` function, something like this:

```
wp_redirect('http://example.com/custom', $status );
```

Comment: @Resolution inside the `wp-login.php`

Answer (score 0):

Use following code in your **functions.php** file to redirect to another URL.

```
function redirect_login_page(){

 // Store for checking if this page equals wp-login.php
 $page_viewed = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

 // Where we want them to go
 $login_page  = http://example.com/custom; //Write your site URL here.
 // Two things happen here, we make sure we are on the login page
 // and we also make sure that the request isn't coming from a form
 // this ensures that our scripts & users can still log in and out.
 if( $page_viewed == "wp-login.php" && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {

 // And away they go...
  wp_redirect($login_page);
  exit();

 }
}

add_action('init','redirect_login_page');
```